# How to write tests for debug and release configurations

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

I'm writing a library, and behaviour of it differs based on mode if it's debug or release. I want to write a unit-tests `TestDebugBehaviour` and `TestReleaseBehaviour`. Is it possible to setup tests to run in debug/release mode?

Comment: Side note: this is generally bad idea if you plan to let other people to use the library - in many cases only one flavor is developed with/tested and other assumed to work the same. If your library behaves differently it likely will  give unpleasant surprises to users. It may be nicer to provide configuration that let's one switch between your current "debug" and "release" modes without recompiling (as side effect you'll avoid exactly the same problem you making yourself to solve too).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it just throws an exception when running in debug mode. Just as planned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this with preprocessor directives.  I am using xunit in my examples below; you will probably have to decorate your test method with a different attribute.

This test should only execute in debug mode.

```
#if DEBUG

[Fact]
public void ThisIsATestThatWillOnlyRunInDebugMode()
{
    throw new Exception("I am running in debug mode.");
}

#endif
```

This test does not exactly run in release mode specifically, it just runs in any mode except debug mode but that is usually good enough.

```
#if !DEBUG

[Fact]
public void ThisIsATestThatWillNotRunInDebugMode()
{
    throw new Exception("I am running in in something other than debug mode.");
}

#endif
```

Comment: Or #if DEBUG  ... #ELSE ... #endif

Comment: Is that valid approach to write unit tests? Shouldn't unit tests all for both configurations?

Answer (score -1):

No. That is not possible. If you want to make such a comparison, just compile&run it in both release and compare the results. If a method behaves incorrectly in release mode only, use a logger to trace the behavior of that method and check out where things go wrong.